# Set value from input by its name

Tags: javascript, wordpress, input

in my booking form I have an input (email) with concrete name and I want to get this value so I can send an email to this value. I can't much edit code of input since it's pretty complicated WP plugin.

Input code:

```
<input required="required" type="text" name="single-line-text-label---6397382___required" value="" class="large textfield">
```

Code to email send:

```
$to2 = trim(strip_tags($_POST['single-line-text-label---6397382___required']));

wp_mail($to2,$subject,$message);
```

or this one which shows error call to undefined function.

```
$to2 = document.getElementsByClassName("textfield")[0].value;

wp_mail($to2,$subject,$message);
```

The problem is that I don't get any emails, so I suppose $to2 is not got right value, cause if I replace code to $to2 = 'my@email.com' it works fine. 
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: Is the contents of 'single-line-text-label---6397382___required' an actual email address? Change the <input type='email' ...> at least the browser wont allow non-email formatted data through. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php for filtering inputs.

Comment: Yes, content is an email adress, but I can't edit it. It's generated by wordpress plugin.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the people who wrote the plugin? They might have a solution for you.

Comment: Yes, but thir response time is about 24 hours without weekends and this is really urgent. Another thing is, that they take an email from user right from wordpress and send a mail to this email. I want to send it to another (or additional) email which is in this input.

Comment: I'm using it email sending function, I'm not sure how to echo it right so I can see the result.

Comment: Don't you know, if I can get the value from its class "textfield" if I have more elements with that class? Something like "find first" (or ideally find second).

I'm trying this, but it looks only error
    $to2 = document.getElementsByTagName("textfield")[0].value;

Comment: Or can I atleast do some condition if to2 has value? I dont know how